# Android Studio windows not focused after closing a tab with shortcut

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a habit of closing windows with `Command`+`W`, and until recently, I could hold down `Command` and hit `W` multiple times to close more windows.

Lately, I can only close one window, and the next window is shown but is not focused, so the keyboard shortcut does nothing.

Does anyone know the configuration setting to automatically focus the next window that is shown after another is closed?

I'm on Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 2.